# how to make app compatible for both java 1.5 and 1.6?

Tags: java, macos, osx-snow-leopard

We have a java desktop application. App was working fine before updates had been taken and now it isn't working with java 1.6 on mac OS x leopard.

We replaced our **JavaApplicationStub** of app and it's working again from location.

> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub

We are looking to make app compatible for both java 1.5 and 1.6 without replacing **JavaApplicationStub** manually.

- Do we have any other option then replacing **JavaApplicationStub**?
- What change in Info.plist will make our app compatible for both java 1.5 and 1.6?
- Also we would like to know, at present 1.4+ value is being set to JVMVersion key. So why didn't it support for higher version from 1.4, i.e. for java i.5 and java 1.6?

Comment: This question has 2 upvotes, seriously? It isn't even clear what is specifically being asked!

Comment: @bguiz, I was one of those upvotes. Sometimes a question needs some attention to help it become a better question. I generally don't vote up poorly asked questions, but I think there is a question here that is trying to come out, so I wanted to give it a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question could be phrased more clearly... did it stop working in 1.5 or 1.6? Assuming you have the source, what errors do you get when compiling with 1.6?